# How to edit the hadoop.env.sh file through terminal on Mac OS X 10.9.5

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am trying to install hadoop on mac and i am trying to edit the hadoop-env.sh file like below

**vi hadoop-env.sh** but and always saying that the file was in read only format then after google i tried like **sudo vi filename** but the result is same please help me on this how to change the file permissions under user account but not under root account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by changing the owner ship to hadoop account like **chown -R hadoop hadoop-***